# Folder with pipes in the filename missing

Tags: files

I have been backing up my folders, I am using Seagate Expansion portable Drive. I had created a folder called "|o|o" in the root folder of the portable drive... I copied my latest folders into "|o|o" folder to re-install ubuntu.

When I open the portable drive the folder |o|o is not visible, when I ctrl+a and check properties the space used is 122GB, however when I click on the drive to view properties of the drive used space is 260GB. It looks as if the folder is there in the portable drive but I cannot access it... I have tried to view all the hidden files and "|o|o" is still not there. I am using 12.04.Can you please help me to retrieve this folder.

Comment: |o|o?  How did you make that folder? Since | is een restricted character (used for piping commands).  And did you check from command line or from a file browser? If only the latter do the 1st too :) Do you know a file name inside that folder? If so... `cd` to the disc and use `find . -name {file_name} -print` to search for it from that  directory.

Comment: @Rinzwind I right clicked and created new folder named it |o|o, I have checked from command line and file browser and the folder is not there. when running the command you gave it does not return anything it just moves to a new line. I have tried it with different file names.

Comment: @Rinzwind: `|` isn't a restricted character. Only `/` and `\0` are. It's quite easy to use pipes in filenames, especially if you're using a GUI instead of the command line.

Comment: Yes it is @ScottSeverance Try to do a `mkdir |o|o` in command line. Won't work because of the use of a  special character. 
| is for piping commands. Hence I was wondering if it might be related. Well from another standpoint: I myself would -never- -ever- consider to use a | in a filename ;)

Comment: Actually, it works just fine if you escape it properly. `mkdir \|o\|o` works just fine. Try it. Of course, files with such names can be inconvenient to use with some command line tools, but my personal philosophy is to use any character that enhances a file name's human readability without regard to command line tools (except when I'm programming) and let the tools cope with the names. After many years of such a philosophy, I've yet to experience a significant problem. The name currently under discussion wouldn't fit my philosophy, however, as its meaning is rather opaque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work from your OS, just ignore the part about the live cd. it will work since its on your external HDD.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: Thank you penner, I used Testdisk to recover the hard drive.  It ran for over 24 hours.